# Remove Duplicate String and display unique String in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

I created a roAssociativeArray Object and add multiple strings in Roku. Like Below

```
Nikunj
Ronak
Raxit
Suhag
Nikunj
Suhag
Suhag
Nikunj
Ronak
Nikunj
```

here I tried to remove a duplicate value and display only unique value. Is It possible in Roku?
I needed below output :

```
Nikunj
Ronak
Raxit
Suhag
```

In C# Its possible like below

```
ChDate = ChDate.Distinct().ToList();
```

But I don't know how Is it work in Roku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roku does not have a built-in method to extract unique values from an array, you have to build your own.

There are multiple ways of implementing this, here's one option using a hash table (associative array) to keep track of all the stored values:

```
function unique(arr as Object)
  res = []
  table = {}
  for each v in arr
    k = v.toStr()
    if not table.doesExist(k)
      res.push(v)
      table[k] = true
    end if
  end for
  return res
end function
```

Usage:

```
dupValues = ["Nikunj", "Ronak", "Raxit", "Suhag", "Nikunj", "Suhag", "Suhag", "Nikunj", "Ronak", "Nikunj"]
uniqueValues = unique(dupValues)
?"uniqueValues "uniqueValues
```

Output:

> [
>       "Nikunj", 
>       "Ronak", 
>       "Raxit", 
>       "Suhag" ]

Notice how before storing into the hash table, the value is converted to a string (in case is not), this is so that this function can also accept an array of numbers.

```
dupValues = [3, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 6]
uniqueValues = unique(dupValues)
?"uniqueValues "uniqueValues
```

Output:

> [
>       3, 
>       4, 
>       1, 
>       6, 
>       7 ]

Comment: Thank you for your Great answer Its Working Both type String as Well Numeric Value.